# Importing error with pygame.locals

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game on Python using pygame. I have been using tutorials online and all of them say I should import pygame.locals. But everytime I run this, this error: ImportError: No module named locals.

Any help?

Comment: Do the other pygame imports work?  If you just do import pygame, does that throw an ImportError?

Comment: a guess: change your script name to something other than pygame

Answer (score -1):

You likely have not imported pygame first.

You need to import pygame before you can import pygame.locals, so you'd have to have

```
import pygame
import pygame.locals
```